# How much space does the localstorage key itself take up?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Lets say i create a localstorage key and give it an empty string. Does the name of the keyitem take up the same amount of space as the value would per character?

for instance does

```
localStorage.setItem("keyitem","") 
//Equal the space of this other one under?
localStorage.setItem("key","item");
```

Also, does the amount of keys matter? for instance

```
localStorage.setItem("key","");
//Equal the amount of storage as the 3 under combined? 
localStorage.setItem("k","");
localStorage.setItem("o","");
localStorage.setItem("h","");
```

Comment: The amount of keys is pretty much binary - `0` or `1`. You cannot have multiple keys with the same name, multiple calls to `setItem` just overwrite the previous value.

Comment: This is browser specific as each browser stores their data differently, ie chrome/firefox I believe use sqlite dbs, opera xml files

Comment: Keep in mind that this is probably just what the browser want's to do with it. I guess it would store 16 or 32 bit strings as both key and value. But I'm not sure. (What the browser wants to do with it being: They implement it differently, probs)

Comment: I edited to different keyitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a function once to calculate the size of the `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` objects, but I can't remember where I found it.

Here's the code:

```
Storage.prototype.size = function(units) {
    'use strict';
    units = units ? units.toUpperCase() : 'MB';
    var size = unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this))).length;
    switch (units) {
        case 'B': return [size,'B'].join(' ');
        case 'KB': return [+(size / 1024).toFixed(3),'KB'].join(' ');
        default: return [+(size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(3),'MB'].join(' ');
    }
};
```

I decided to go ahead and run some tests in various browsers.

> Firefox (37.0.2):
>
> [image: Firefox console output]

> Chrome (42.0.2311.90 m):
>
> [image: Chrome console output]

> IE 11 (11.0.9600.17420):
>
> [image: IE Console Output]

> Opera (29.0.1795.47):
>
> [image: Opera console output]

So it looks like FireFox, Chrome, and Opera (probably Safari as well, but I don't have that) all have the same behavior, and keys take up far more space than their values.

In IE (good old IE...), the implementation is executed in a way such that it doesn't matter how you store something.

Comment: I'll quote a comment on a later answer: "This does not show how much space the actual key takes up. This just shows the amount of characters a JSON representation of localStorage has. Each browser implements its own way of saving data. Each of those methods may store the data completely differently than the other. For instance one may use utf8 encoding while the other may use utf16 (meaning the use of 2 bytes to represent 1 character), some may use compression, etc. –  Patrick Evans". This applies to your method as well -- you just measure the JSON string. (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) And the IE implementation doesn't really look different from here. The problem is with the key `key` -- in most implementations, that isn't included the the JSON representation. Apparently IE does include it in this case. Therefore, you're getting the JSON `{"keyitem":""}` which is 14 bytes for the first, and `{}` for the second. In IE, it's `{"key":"item"}` for the second. So you can't really tell from here. -1

Comment: @Scimonster And I will quote a response to the comment you quoted: "I agree, but is the best proxy to understand what gets stored in the localStorage. - Jaco de Groot"

Answer (score 1):

> Does the name of the keyitem take up the same amount of space as the
>   value would per character?

No, it is not necessary. The amount of space taken by key could be more than the amount of space taken by value. But together the space taken by key and value should be approx 5MB(*although this differs with browser as it is browser dependent*)

You can use this code to test:

```
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.setItem(new Array(5e6).join(' '),'');
localStorage.key(0).length;
```

Output on Chrome for the above test:

[image]

So as long as it [`comes under 5MB`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space)([which is mostly the upper limit for most browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values/25812530#25812530)) your key can have any length

Comment: Also to mention that 5MB is equal to 2.5 Million characters on Chrome. Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333807/does-html5-localstorage-maximum-size-include-key-names/11333871#11333871

Comment: @Rahil Tripathi Would u in that case say that 5MB also is equal to 2.5 Million  localStorage.setItem("h",""); which also only contain one character?

Comment: @mattias:- No, that is the upper limit(*that too is specific to browsers*). You can run the test which I have added in your browser(*In firefox is making approx 2.94MB for me*) and you will get the space which your key is taking. In case when you are using key as 'k' then it is not 5MB. Does that make sense now?

Comment: @mattias:- So if you want to check like `localStorage.setItem("kgfdshfgsdhfdksfd.........2.5million characters","");` You will get that the space is coming close to 5MB atleast in Chrome

Comment: Okay well that answers that the key takes equal space as the value itself i suppose, cant see the test u added? which link is it supposed to be? ye it's different upper values but what i meant was, if there is 2.5 million different localstorage keys with only one character as the keyname, would that equal one key with a keyname of 2.5 million characers?

Comment: @mattias:- You can test it on your browser console.

Comment: @mattias:- For the second part of your answer, I would guess that it would be equivalent.

Comment: @mattias:- Added the console result for my test. Also if you want you can increase `5e6` to `5e7` and you will see the difference! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine this yourself by using the JSON `stringify` methods to turn the  localStorage object into a JSON Object:

```
JSON.stringify(localStorage).length
```

This will not return the actual size of the key as data can be stored as utf16 (2 bytes) or utf8 (1 byte), but it is a good proxy for the actual size. See a code snippet below:

```
 localStorage.clear()
 localStorage.setItem("keyitem","") 
 document.write(JSON.stringify(localStorage).length+'</br>')

 //Equal the space of this other one under?
 localStorage.setItem("key","item");
 document.write(JSON.stringify(localStorage).length+'</br>')

 localStorage.clear();
 localStorage.setItem("key","");
 document.write(JSON.stringify(localStorage).length+'</br>')


 //Equal the amount of storage as the 3 under combined? 
 localStorage.setItem("k","");
 localStorage.setItem("o","");
 localStorage.setItem("h","");
 document.write(JSON.stringify(localStorage).length+'</br>')
```

Comment: So you're saying all browsers store it as a JSON string? I guess this makes sense as it is Javascript Object Notation, but how'd you know?
I am of interest

Comment: What's your answer? I have no idea what you determined in your jsFiddle, and jsFiddle isn't loading for me right now. This is why we put all the important details directly here instead of on some other crappy site.

Comment: My apologies, this code snippet doesn't work on StackOverflow itself.

Comment: This does not show how much space the actual key takes up. This just shows the amount of characters a JSON representation of localStorage has. Each browser implements its own way of saving data. Each of those methods may store the data completely differently than the other. For instance one may use utf8 encoding while the other may use utf16 (meaning the use of 2 bytes to represent 1 character), some may use compression, etc.

Comment: I agree, but is the best proxy to understand what gets stored in the localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is an implementation detail for what is concerning the real structure of the storage on disk.

In practice you are given a certain amount of space per origin (usually 5MiB, to check the actual storage you can use this [test tool](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) linked in the MDN documentations) and you can store data (both in terms of keys and values) as long as you don't exceed that size, as shown in a previous answer. So yes the [keys are included in the storage quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333807/does-html5-localstorage-maximum-size-include-key-names).

As it points out in the test tool I included, chars are actually UTF-16 so they takes up 2 bytes of your storage quota.

Also note that the storage stores strings, this means that if you put a large float as key or value you are not storing it in its binary format but as strings!

```
// These takes up the same space
localStorage.setItem("a", 123);
localStorage.setItem("a", "123");
```

In fact if you try to do typeof of the following you get `string` in both cases

```
localStorage.setItem("123", "");
localStorage.setItem(123, "");
typeof localStorage.key(0); // returns "string"
typeof localStorage.key(1); // returns "string" as well
```

As for the second part, in terms of storage this

```
localStorage.setItem("k","");
localStorage.setItem("o","");
localStorage.setItem("h","");
```

should take 3 chars of storage from your quota, that is 3 * 2 bytes if using UTF-16 or 3 bytes if using UTF-8.

For an overview of local storage solutions you can check here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test in Chrome and was able to prove that the key takes up exactly as much space as the length.

With a key of `abc`, i was able to set a value of length 5242877. With a key of `a`, i was able to set a value of length 5242879. As you can see, removing characters from the key freed up those 2 for the value.

Comment: okay great! what about " if there is 2.5 million(for instance) different localstorage keys with only one character as the keyname, would that equal one key with a keyname of 2.5 million characers in space?"

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it.